# Can't use services inside a catchError function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to have a generic way of handling exceptions, expecially 401's received from the backend. When I don't extract the catchError content, it works fine. However if I simply extract it to a specific function, then nothing gets injected in that function:

```
return this.http.request<T>(new HttpRequest('POST', this.appConfig.baseApiPath + url, file, {
            reportProgress: true,
            headers: headers,
            params: urlParams
        })).pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login?expired=true');
                }
                return Observable.throw(err || 'Server error')
            })
        );
```

This works! However I wanted to handle this redirect code in a function in order to reuse it by other methods.

Here I exported that into a function:

```
    return this.http.request<T>(new HttpRequest('POST', this.appConfig.baseApiPath + url, file, {
        reportProgress: true,
        headers: headers,
        params: urlParams
    })).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleHttpError),
    );

handleHttpError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login?expired=true'); --> router is null!
    }
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
}
```

And that's where router (as well as other constructor injected services) are null if I use that way of working... could you suggest why?

Comment: 1. you did not post the full code, especially the part you have your router declared 2. why don't you just use [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that you're losing context. When function is declared in such way `this` keyword is about scope of the function, not the whole class. Not to lose context you shoud use an arrow function:

```
handleHttpError = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login?expired=true');
    }
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
}
```

Answer (score 8):

a better approach is to bind 'this' to your call:

```
catchError(this.handleHttpError.bind(this))
```